# Unable to start-hbase.sh (throws error)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

When I `start-hbase.sh`, I get the following error

```
localhost: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/lib/HBase/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-zookeeper-nkhl.out
localhost: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hduser/zookeeperpropertydataDir/myid (Permission denied)
localhost:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
localhost:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
localhost:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
localhost:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
localhost:  at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:263)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.writeMyID(HQuorumPeer.java:162)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:70)
starting master, logging to /usr/lib/HBase/logs/hbase-hduser-master-nkhl.out
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
regionserver running as process 25123. Stop it first.
```

After this, when I do `hbase shell`, it does open up, but when I `list` it throws this error:

```
ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

    Here is some help for this command:
    List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
    be used to filter the output. Examples:

      hbase> list
      hbase> list 'abc.*'
      hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
      hbase> list 'ns:.*'
```

This is `jps`:

```
25123 HRegionServer
23975 SecondaryNameNode
23767 DataNode
24168 ResourceManager
26456 HMaster
26665 Jps
24297 NodeManager
23613 NameNode
```

Zookeeper starts fine:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default Using config:
/usr/lib/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

My hbase-site.xml configuration:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:54433/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/zookeeperpropertydataDir</value>
    </property>

    <property >
        <name>hbase.master.port</name>
            <value>60010</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
            <value>2181</value>
            <description> The port at which the clients will connect.</description>
        </property>


</configuration>
```

This is my `hbase-env.sh` configuration:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=${HBASE_HOME}/conf/regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hbase zookeeper deamon `HQuorumPeer` is not running. one of the reason can be below dir doesn't exist as shown in logs:-

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/zookeeperpropertydataDir</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: It is right that `HQuorumPeer` isn't running. But rest assured, the directory does exist. I have created it. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: If it means anything it also has these files:
`myid`, `zookeeper_server.pid`

And this directory: `version-2`

Comment: No one got an answer?

Comment: Also, is it necessary to have Zookeeper installed before HBase?

Comment: Still nothing? Anyone?

Comment: Yes, `HQuorumPeer` is required to be installed for `HBASE` to work properly. Check this code, it does require atleast `id` and `datadir`. https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/zookeeper/HQuorumPeer.html . search for these words in code, you will get to know. what things are required HBase Zookeeper to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read [here] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/37230/hbase-installation-failure), that if I have separately installed Zookeeper, which I have, I will have to make this change: `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false`. I tried it, but doesn't work.

Comment: How can I separately install  HQuorumPeer?

Comment: No one wants to answer this? No one?

Comment: Surprised no one wants to answer this!

Comment: @AnonymousPerson - Please comment in question part . I think it is not visible to community if comments are in answer part.

Comment: It's not that. If I click on "Answer Your Question" it means I will be answering my own question. This isn't resolved so I can't do that yet. Can you help with this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file that ZooKeeper is using has been created and has the right privileges.
Use chmod to grant access to all users. This fixed my problem.

```sh
chmod -R 777 path/file_name
```

```xml
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/home/hduser /zookeeperpropertydataDir</value>
</property>
```